# Debugging Worker thread in electron

Tags: electron

I'm testing out worker_thread on an electron application.  I'm currently using version 11.0.2.

The code is simple and is working and returning the sample data but I cant seem to step into the code.

Main Process:

```
import { Worker, isMainThread, workerData } from 'worker_threads';


  config.ipcMain.on('entries:search', (evt: any, opts: any) => {
    if (isMainThread) {
        const pathWorker = path.join(__dirname, '../data/entries_worker.js');
        const worker = new Worker(pathWorker, {
            workerData: opts.value,
        });
        worker.on('message', (data) => {
            debugger;
            const d = 1;
        });

        worker.on('error', (data) => {
            debugger;
            const d = 1;
        });

        worker.on('exit', (data) => {
            debugger;
            const d = 1;
        });
    }
  });
```

The worker file code:

```
import { workerData, parentPort } from 'worker_threads';
debugger;
parentPort.postMessage({ status: 'Done' });
```

I'm using Visual Studio Code and I do put breakpoints and event the debugger statement but it never seems to break into the worker file.

The message event does receive the response from the script { status: 'Done' } and the exit event returns 0.

Any ideas on how I can stop at the breakpoint in the worker file entries_worker.js?

**Update**

Found the following [link](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/26609) about how it's not available right now.  I'm not 100% sure if it has changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ndb](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/ndb) allow debugger worker thread. run in develop env like this:

```
"electron-dev": "ndb electron ."
```

When you use worker thread, you can found it easy:
[image]

You can also add breakpoints debug your code:
[image]